# Convert Jetty Buffer to InputStream

Tags: java, jetty, inputstream

I have to parse xml from the content of a Jetty buffer using `SAX`.
From my `ContentExchange` I can call `getRequestContent`, and then I get a `Buffer`

I need an `InputStream`, or an `InputSoruce` or a `String` or a `File` in order to parse it with `SAX`. How can I convert the buffer to one of those, and which way is the most efficient?

It looks like something obvious, but I can not find any information in the documentation.

Comment: Can you call `new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.array())`?  `Buffer` has an array method I believe: http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6/apidocs/org/mortbay/io/Buffer.html#array()

Comment: That would be memory-consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for answering an old question, but someone (such as myself) may stumble upon this in the future.

Jetty's `Buffer` class implements a `writeTo(OutputStream)` method. A simple solution would be to do the following:

```
PipedInputStream is = new PipedInputStream();
PipedOutputStream os = new PipedOutputStream(is);
```

Then for each `Buffer` received, do:

```
void processBuffer(Buffer buf) {
    buf.writeTo(os);
}
```

This way you can stream responses without need for caching them.

EDIT:

Of course, make sure that `processBuffer()` and readers of the `PipedInputStream` are running in separate threads to avoid potential deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could wrap the buffer in your own custom (anonymous?) [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) since you only need to implement the [`read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) method.  For example:

```
public InputStream forBuffer(final Buffer buf) {
  return new InputStream() {
    @Override
    public int read() /* throws IOException */ {
      return buf.get();
    }
  };
}
```

From the Jetty docs it's hard to tell what happens when the [`Buffer#get()` method](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6/apidocs/org/mortbay/io/Buffer.html#get%28%29) hits the end but some simple testing should reveal it (and if it happens to return `-1` then this example is complete!).